# Should I use single or double pairs of attribute's quotes?

Tags: angular

Which form should I use for such attributes?
[id]="with-hyphen" [id]="'with-hyphen'"
Does just one pair of double quotes are okay for attribute with hyphen? Or should I additionally put text in single quotes fires?

It is about Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing in a property you would use single quotes. For example if you have component A that has an @Input() bId and you have component B with a property id you would pass it in like this:

```
<componentA [id]="bId"></componentA>
```

If on the other hand you want to pass in a string directly to componentA you can use nested quotes:

```
<componentA [id]="'whatever string you want'"></componentA>
```

When it comes to html elements like like img and you're passing in the src  it is treated like a string.

```
<img src="http://somesite.com/funnypic.png">
```

But if you want to pass in a variable to the src property you can use string interpolation {{}} and pass in a variable that is set in your component like this:

```
<img src="{{aComponentVariable}}">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer. So am I thinking correctly that  `[id]="with-hyphen"` will be fine?

Answer (score 1):

```
`[id]="with-hyphen" `
```

This is wrong.

when you put the attribute inside a bracket, you're binding to the variable that you're providing, and in javascript , variables cannot have `-` dash.

Whereas

```
id="with-hyphen"
```

This is right, because you're not binding to a variable, you're rather passing a normal string